# Navigating a 4D dataset

Tags: dm-script

For a 3D dataset, GMS 3 will assign a slice tool to navigate the 3rd dimension - typically used to navigate EELS and EDS SIs.

For a 4D dataset, this is not the case - in fact, no slider appears at all, nevermind two.

I would like to create a small GUI with sliders for each additional dimension beyond the two "image" dimensions, but I'm not sure what command is used to change the visible slice on the screen. I'd appreciate it if someone could help.

As for creating a small 4D image, it can be done with the collowing code:

```
image A = IntegerImage("", 2, 0, 16, 16, 16, 16)
ShowImage(A)
```

Comment: As it happens, I have been developing a framework based on DM-script that has built-in support for exploring and extracting slices from data sets of arbitrary dimension, including 4D images of the sort you mention.  I am currently providing this Enabler framework free of charge to the research community and will present a late-breaking poster on it at this year's M&M meeting.  If you are interested, please contact me at the info email address posted on the Web page given in my profile.

Answer (score 1):

The slice tool for 4D is a *licensed* tool - then it works out of the box.
But if you want to build a proxy by script, you can do this.
The commands for getting/setting the "displayed" slices in a 3D and 4D display are the following:

```
void ImageDisplayGetDisplayedLayers( ImageDisplay imgDisp, NumberVariable start, NumberVariable end )
void ImageDisplayGetDisplayedLayers( ImageDisplay imgDisp, NumberVariable start1, NumberVariable end1, NumberVariable start2, NumberVariable end2 )

void ImageDisplaySetDisplayedLayers( ImageDisplay imgDisp, Number start, Number end )
void ImageDisplaySetDisplayedLayers( ImageDisplay imgDisp, Number start1, Number end1, Number start2, Number end2 )
```

[image: F1 help documentation]

Here is an example of how to use them:

```
image Img := realimage("4D Data", 4, 3, 5, 7, 9 )
Img = 10000 + idimindex(0) + 10 * idimindex(1) + 100 * idimindex(2) + 1000 * idimindex(3)
Img.ShowImage()
imageDisplay disp = A.ImageGetImageDisplay(0)

number start1,start2
number end1,end2

disp.ImageDisplayGetDisplayedLayers(start1,end1,start2,end2)
ClearResults()
Result( "Current Display Sliders are:" )
Result( "\n 3rd dim:" + start1 + " - " + end1 )
Result( "\n 4th dim:" + start2 + " - " + end2 )

OKDialog( "Now setting..." )
disp.ImageDisplaySetDisplayedLayers(start1,end1,start2+2,end2+2)
disp.ImageDisplayGetDisplayedLayers(start1,end1,start2,end2)
Result( "Current Display Sliders are now:" )
Result( "\n 3rd dim:" + start1 + " - " + end1 )
Result( "\n 4th dim:" + start2 + " - " + end2 )
```

---

> However, I have just checked the free version of GMS 3.2.2 as [downloaded from Gatan's webpage](http://www.gatan.com/installation-instructions). 
>   If you use the **SI Viewer** license (which is free), then the 4D slice-tool works just fine. As does the 4D picker-tool, apparently.

[image: GMS 3.2.2 with SI VIEWER free license]